# Logging in Python. Handlers and console duplicates

Tags: python, logging

I have a simple logging setup:

```
def main()

  # ....
  # Create logger
  logging.basicConfig(filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  # Create file handler for DEBUG and above
  fh1 = logging.FileHandler(__name__ + '.debug.log')
  fh1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  # Create file handler for INFO and above
  fh2 = logging.FileHandler(__name__ + '.info.log')
  fh2.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  # Create console handler with INFO and above
  ch = logging.StreamHandler()
  ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  # Add all the handlers to the logger
  logger.addHandler(fh1)
  logger.addHandler(fh2)
  logger.addHandler(ch)
  # ....
```

Then when I call

```
logger.info("this is an INFO message")
logger.debug("this is a DEBUG message")
```

I get the following on the console:

```
this is an INFO message
INFO:__main__:this is an INFO message
this is a DEBUG message
DEBUG:__main__:this is a DEBUG message
```

Even though I expected to only see `INFO` messages in the console (since I specified `logging.info` above for the `StreamHandler`). Why do I get these duplicates?

My `.debug.log` and `info.log` files contain only the messages at the right level, but their formatting does not include the prefices `INFO:__main__` nor `DEBUG:__main__`. Why is their formatting different?

Comment: why set the level=DEBUG, I always use `logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')` Also have in mind that logger instances are singleton, so maybe setting 2 handlers is making it repeat messages in 2 levels, INFO and DEBUG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
logging.basicConfig(filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

creates a `StreamHandler`. So your code is creating two `StreamHandlers`, one with logging level `DEBUG` and another with level `INFO`.

`basicConfig` is a convenience function. If you want to create your own handlers, it is not necessary to call `basicConfig`. (Or you can call `basicConfig` and add additional handlers...)

---

If you don't supply a filename in the call to `basicConfig`, then a `StreamHandler` is added to the root logger. This is the code [inside the `basicConfig` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3744b6ad8c3f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1734):

```
if handlers is None:
    filename = kwargs.get("filename")
    if filename:
        mode = kwargs.get("filemode", 'a')
        h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
    else:
        stream = kwargs.get("stream")
        h = StreamHandler(stream)
```