# any workaround to fetch log message from python console when flask app is used?

Tags: python, logging, backend

I want to make log files when I run my minimal flask app, basically, I want to log all logging messages from the python console when different endpoints are used. To do so, I used a flask logging mechanism but couldn't catch logging messages including a running sessions on python concole, logging info from testing different endpoints with the specific routes. How can I catch running session info from python console? How do I make log for errors, warning, session info from python console? Is there any way to make this happen? any thought?

**my current attempt**

here is my current attempt which failed to catch log info on python console:

```
import os, logging, logging.handlers, traceback
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, Namespce,fields, reqparse, inputs

def primes_method1(n):
    out = list()
    for num in range(1, n+1):
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i == 0):
                prime = False
        if prime:
            out.append(num)
    return out

def getLogger(logname, logdir, logsize=500*1024, logbackup_count=4):
    if not os.path.exists(logdir):
        os.makedirs(logdir)
    logfile='%s/%s.log' % (logdir, logname)
    loglevel = logging.INFO
    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
    logger.setLevel(loglevel)
    if logger.handlers is not None and len(logger.handlers) >= 0:
        for handler in logger.handlers:
            logger.removeHandler(handler)
        logger.handlers = []
    loghandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        logfile, maxBytes=logsize, backupCount=logbackup_count)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(name)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
    loghandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(loghandler)
    return logger

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
ns = api.namespace('ns')

payload = api.model('Payload', {
    'num': fields.Integer(required=True)
})

logger = getLogger('testLog', '~/')

@ns.route('/primenumber')
class PrimeResource(Resource):
    @ns.expect(payload)
    def post(self):
        logger.info("get prime number")
        param = request.json['num']
        try: 
            res = primes_method1(param)
            return jsonify({'output': res})
        except:
            return None, 400

ns1 = Namespce('')
@ns1.route('/log')
class logResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        logger.info("return saved all logers from above endpoints")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.add_namespace(ns)
    api.add_namespace(ns1)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

basically, when I test endpoint with sample data, I want to see all logged messages at `@ns1.route('/log')` endpoint. In my attempt, I couldn't catch running session info on python console. How to log flask running session info on python console? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I've not used Flask (only django), but I think you might want to look into creating another handler for your logger that logs to console.

Comment: @ShioT can you be specific? any coding attempt you might suggest or post as an answer? thanks

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate but it should help. I'm on mobile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540479/logging-in-python-handlers-and-console-duplicates

Comment: @ShioT I didn't quite follow. Do you mind possible answer if you have something in your mind?

Comment: My answer isn't tested. Please try it out for yourself.

Comment: @ShioT it still didn't fetch running session from python console, didn't make any difference still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't really related to Flask, unless I'm overlooking something unique to Flask that doesn't conform to the logging interface. This isn't a workaround either, just normal usage of the tools.

Try to add a handler to your logger like so:

```
loghandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    logfile, maxBytes=logsize, backupCount=logbackup_count)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(name)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
loghandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
loghandler2 = logging.StreamHandler()
loghandler2.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(loghandler2)
return logger
```